# Regex to get first two words of unknown length from a string

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a string with various words of unknown length. I plan to split the string by using a regular expression. Something like:

```
String resString = origString.split(".*//s.*//s")[0];
```

What would be the regular expression to get the first two words? I was thinking `.*//s.*//s`, so all characters, followed by a space, then all characters, followed by another space. But using that gives me the exact same string I had before. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You must be Prisoner of Bill, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have only spaces between words, split by `\\s+`. When you split, the array would be the words themselves. First two would be in `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` if you do:

```
String[] arr = origString.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 6):

With regular expressions you can do something like this:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> split2(String line, int n){
    line+=" ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find()){
        if(i!=n)
            list.add(matcher.group());
        else
            break;
        i++;
    }
    return list;
}
```

if you want the first n words, or simply this:

```
    public static String split3(String line){
    line+=" ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*\\s\\w*\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    matcher.find();
    return matcher.group();
}
```

if you want only the first and second words.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to split it on exactly the space character:

```
String[] parts = args[i].split(" ");
```

If you want to split it on any whitespace character (space, tab, newline, cr):

```
String[] parts = args[i].split("\\s");
```

To treat multiple adjacent spaces as one separator:

```
String[] parts = args[i].split(" +");
```

Same for whitespace:

```
String[] parts = args[i].split("\\s+");
```

The first two words would be `parts[0]` and `parts[1]`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your "words" consist of alphanumeric characters, the following regex will match the first 2 words:

```
\w+\s+\w+
```

Comment: "\\w+\\s+\\w+" will work in Java. I was referring to generic regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method.

```
public static String firstLettersOfWord(String word) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String[] myName = word.split("\\s+");

    for (String s : myName) {
        result.append(s.charAt(0));
    }
    return result.toString();
}}
```